# Как в переменную в bash файле записать вывод команды git pull?

Tags: git, bash, git-pull

Пишу скрипт для локального перехода на ту ветку, в которую был сделан самый последний пуш в удалённом репозитории (подразумевается, что push в любом случае был сделан). 
Через команду git pull, находясь при этом на любой ветке в локал репозитории, хочу получить информацию о последнем коммите (не в конкретную ветку, а вообще, абсолютно последний).
Выполняя команду git pull получаю:

```
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From gitlab.mycompany.by:kek/test-proj
   05ec137..1e3a195  feature-128 -> origin/feature-128
```

В bash файле у меня всё выглядит след. образом:

```
var1=$(git pull) #или в знаках апострофа git pull
echo "Переменная var1:"
echo "$var1"
```

Хочу, чтобы весь текст с git pull сохранился в переменную var1. Однако, на выходе вижу

```
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From gitlab.mycompany.by:kek/test-proj
   05ec137..1e3a195  feature-128 -> origin/feature-128
Already up-to-date.
Переменная var1:
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, присвоить результат выполнения git pull переменной.

Comment: А stderr вы не забыли перенаправить?

Comment: @0xdb, если б я знал. Отсилы неделя опыта в изучении git-а. 
Вот, например, такая комбинация запросто прокатывает: `lastCommitInfo=$(git show --name-status)`.
 Вывод команды могу получить по выводу переменной через echo
Но с git pull не найду решения всё никак

Comment: `var1=$(git pull 2>&1)`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, напишите ответом, чтобы можно было его отметить, это правильный вариант, спасибо!

Comment: ```var2=`git pull 2>&1` ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIT выводит информативные сообщения, как в случае с `git show ...`, `git satus ...` и т.д. на стандартный поток вывода (*`stdout`*). Сообщения содержащие прогрес выполнения и диагностическую информацию, как и в случае с `git pull ...`, выводятся на поток вывода ошибок (*`stderr`*).

Надо перенаправить поток ошибок на дескриптор стандартного потока вывода:

```
var1=$(git pull 2>&1)
```

Или воспользоваться переменной окружения `GIT_REDIRECT_STDERR='2>&1'`, если доступна, см. [man git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITREDIRECTSTDERRcode).